# How to move camera as First Person?

Tags: c++, directx

I'm developing a first-person camera in my project of DirectX, the problem is that I don't know how to move my mesh with the camera, It only works like a normal camera that can move around the world and can rotate with the mouse, but can move it with the mesh, It only stays static.

I already try to multiply my view matrix with the Matrix of the Mesh, but it seems to make a really weird thing like deforming the mesh or getting a wrong perspective.

This is my code that moves the camera :

```
void CManager::cameraMove(ID3D11DeviceContext* &pImmediateContext, ID3D11Buffer*&pCBNeverChanges, WPARAM wParam, float xPos, float yPos)
{
    if (wParam == 37) // Left
    {
        Camera.g_View *= XMMatrixTranslation(m_Cx, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        //DwarfMatrix = Camera.g_View;
        //DwarfMatrix *= translate;
    }
    else if (wParam == 'W') // Front
    {
        Camera.g_View *= XMMatrixTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, -m_Cz);
    }
    else if (wParam == 39) // Right
    {
        Camera.g_View *= XMMatrixTranslation(-m_Cx, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        //DwarfMatrix *= translateN;
    }
    else if (wParam == 'S') // Back
    {
        Camera.g_View *= XMMatrixTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, m_Cz);
    }
    else if (wParam == 38) // Up
    {
        Camera.g_View *= XMMatrixTranslation(0.0f, -m_Cy, 0.0f);
    }
    else if (wParam == 40) // Down
    {
        Camera.g_View *= XMMatrixTranslation(0.0f, m_Cy, 0.0f);
    }
    else if (wParam == 'C') // Change Texture
    {
        camChange();
    }

    Camera.cbNeverChanges.mView = XMMatrixTranspose(Camera.g_View);
    pImmediateContext->UpdateSubresource(NeverChangeBuffer.m_Buffer, 0, NULL, &Camera.cbNeverChanges, 0, 0);
}
```

And here is the code of my model with his matrix:

```
XMMATRIX ModelMatrix = XMMATRIX(
        .03f, 0.0f, 0.0f, m_x,
        0.0f, .03f, 0.0f, m_y,
        0.0f, 0.0f, .03f, m_z,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    );

// Asign the Model to his matrix in render
g_manager.m_mesh[i].m_object.mWorld = g_manager.ModelMatrix;
```

I expect to move the mesh with the camera matrix or with some matrix attached to the camera. I already have the camera working but not as I expect with the model.

Comment: Transforming the mesh: I guess there happens some shearing, non-uniform scaling or even projection (or a combination of it). Shearing: vectors of upper left 3x3 matrix are not orthogonal. Non-uniform scaling: Length of vectors in upper-left 3x3 matrix is not 1. Projection: Last row is not (0, 0, 0, 1). The latter happens if accidentally a transposed matrix is assumed. In math, the translation is last column but I saw many libs which store matrix vectors row-wise. It's confusing sometimes... ;-)

Comment: It could be, I will check my mesh matrix to see if I'm shearing correctly the information, thanks!

Comment: I must admit I'm an OpenGL fellow. However, I studied the [XMMATRIX structure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/directxmath/ns-directxmath-xmmatrix) and the constructor you used in your last sample. I got the impression that `m_x`, `m_y`, `m_z` have to be in last row instead of last column. I might be wrong but that's easy to check out. Alternatively, you could make a matrix with `XMMatrixTranslation` and watch in which `struct` members x, y, z appear. If my suspicion is right, you made a strange projection matrix as `ModelMatrix.` (See last part of my previous comment.)

Comment: I believe my suspicion is correct: Have a look at this: [SO: Translate - Rotate - Translate Back using XMMATRIX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31823174/7478597) _(i.e. the last column is `[0 0 0 1]`)_ or this nice tutorial: [03. DirectX 11 - Braynzar Soft Tutorials - 09. Transformations](https://www.braynzarsoft.net/viewtutorial/q16390-9-transformations).